Background thread processing vs queue based processing for relatively short tasks (max 30-40 seconds)
I need suggestion / recommendation on the design approaches mentioned below.
UseCase: I have a usecase where a client uses my system to generate some recommendations. Now, these recommendations are generated in 2 phases. In the first phase, client sends some payload and I make a DB call and a service call to generate an intermediate recommendation. This process takes around 30-40 seconds. In the second phase, cliend sends some additional data and I filter the intermediate recommendations with that additional data. In the second phase I make a DB call and a smaller LLM model (so the average latency would be 3-5 seconds. Following are my questions.
For the first phase, there are three approaches.

I ask the client to push a message to FIFO Queue, and a poller within my service polls the message.
I could be to create a standard API, accept the request and start the task execution on a separate thread.
The third approach is same as above, just that instead of processing in background pushing a message to a queue, and a consumer will poll for messages.

3rd one is ruled out as it doesn't offer much value and I will always have 1 client, Amongst 1 and 2, I am more aligned on #2, because using a queue looks like an overkill here. Does anyone have any thoughts on this?
For the second phase, there are 2 approaches

Implementing a blocking API where I wait for the smaller model call to complete.
Implement a status message based API where on first call I accept and process the smaller llm call on a separate thread, and then let the client poll and i could return with either in-progress or success call.

I am preferring approach 1 here, since it keeps things simple (as the max latency I would want for this API would be 2-3 seconds). However, the downside is that the system resources would be held (threads). Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

How should the situation be handled when a second request for a preliminary recommendation comes in while the preceding request is still being processed? Should that be processed in parallel or should the processing of the second request be delayed until the preceding request has been completely handled?

Note that when you are waiting for a response, 30 to 40 seconds is a really long time. Even 2 to 3 seconds will feel as sluggish if you don´t give proper feedback to the user. Keep that in mind as well when designing your system.

Hi @BartvanIngenSchenau , Thanks for the reply. If the second request comes before the preceding request is completed. We need not worry about it, and would give a fallback recommendation because second request is latency sensitive.

The deciding factor for me between a queue based response and a thread based response would be:

The volume of concurrent requests that are needed to be serviced
How the API is hosted.
The fault tolerance required around a duplicate and/or failed request.

If you are thinking that you will have more concurrent requests than hyper threads available on your server's CPU's then you should start to think about queuing requests.
Wanting fault tolerance also points towards queuing as a strategy.
Hosting the API in the cloud may mean that you have automatic scaling of threading capacity (AWS Lambda) but you still have to think about the database performance. Hitting it with too many simultaneous requests will hurt its performance badly.
